# IBM Notes editable fields getting data from parent form

Tags: formula, lotus-domino, lotusscript

In Notes I have a form (Order) in which I have button "Create new OrderLine" which creates a new form(Orderline). The Order document has an embedded view on the design which gets orderlines documents. Each orderline document contains a hidden field with the ID of the order document, so that you know which orderline is connected with which order. Same goes for Orderline this has an embeddedview with Prices.

In the Order form I have 2 editable text fields: AdministrationNumber and DebtorNumber.

In the OrderlineForm I only got the debtorNumber

In Prices I have a editable number field called Fee.

So I did this on various ways:

In the postOpen of the form prices I have put this LotusScript code:

```
If( (Source.FieldGetText( "AdministrationNumber" ) = "1" ) And   (Source.FieldGetText( "DebtorNumber" ) = "2") ) Then
    Call Source.FieldSetText("FeePercentage",  "4.235")
    Call Source.Refresh()
End If
```

But did not work.

In Default Value of Fee I also tried this formula code:

```
@If((AdministrationNumber="1") & (DebtorNumber= "2");
    "4,235";
        "0"
)
```

But also of no use..

Is it possible for an editable field to be set when opening the subform based on conditional statement with data which is in the parent form?

**Edit**

2 ways to solve:

1.

When clicking "Add  new Orderline" Button whic is on the Order form, I will call a function in the scriptlibrary, in this function I get values of debnr and admnr and then do the conditional statement.. If true then set FeePercentage

2.

Added new hidden field on the orderlline called admnr which gets the administratorNr field data when the New Orderline Button is clicked.. The field is set through a function in the scriptlibrary.

Eventually in the postOpen of the prices subform this works:

```
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Set doc = Source.Document
If doc.admnra(0) = "1" And doc.debnr(0) = "2" Then
    doc.FeePercentage = 4.235
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work with back-end classes instead:

```
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Set doc = Source.Document
If doc.AdministrationNumber(0) = "1" And doc.DebtorNumber(0) = "2" Then
    doc.FeePercentage = 4.235
End If
```

It gives you easy access to all fields in document.

Comment: How to do that then.. because on the Order Form I have a button which opens the prices orderline and prices subform. When users opens the prices form that fee must then also be visible.

Comment: Are you talking about subforms which are included in form "Order" OR about different forms?

Comment: Sorry actually its like this, The form "Order" has a embedded view with orderlines and also a button called "Add new orderline", If user clicks on button "Add New orderline" then a orderline document is opened. In this form there is a subform called "price"  which has a field called "feePercentage" the 4.235 must come here is admnr =1 and debtornumer =2 (which is from the order form)

Comment: That's a different story then... You have separate documents for Order (form Order) and Orderline (form Orderline including subform Price). Get Orderline's parent Order document and access fields AdministrationNumber and DebtorNumber there.

Comment: Remember the difference between documents (=data) and forms (=design)

Comment: Yes when new orderLine document is composed then I now get administrationNumber and Debtornumber and save it also in orderLine document.. If in this code I also give Fee the 4.235 then it wont be set, it gets the default formula value which is 0

Comment: If you set fields AdministrationNumber and DebtorNumber in Orderline document with values from order document earlier then in PostOpen event then my code above works in Orderline's or Price's PostOpen event.

Comment: The editablefield is not changed, I open the document in edit mode

Comment: Editmode doesn't matter.

Comment: If you have only just added the AdministrationNumber and DebtorNumber fields to the OrderLine form, then any documents that existed before you made the change do not have those fields set. The technique Knut is describing (and also the one given by JSmart253) will only work for new OderLine documents. To make it work for the OrderLine documents that already existed, you would have to write an agent that sets those fields by doing a lookup back into the parent Order document. Another alternative would be to use @DbLookup in the default value formula to read those fields directly from the Order.

Comment: Thanks all, it works. I removed the field and readded it again then it worked, maybe I had a wrong setting in the field..

Answer (score 2):

You say "subform" which has a special meaning in Notes design but it sounds like what you have is a form called "Order", a form called "OrderLine" and a subform called "Prices" that the OrderLine form uses?

In which case, make sure the OrderLine's the "Formulas inherit values from selected document" form property is checked.

That and your default formula should do it if the button is on the parent form (as opposed to view the Order form embeds).

P.S. You might want to change your default formula to

```
@If(
  (AdministrationNumber="1") & (DebtorNumber= "2"); 4235;
  0
)
```

so that it returns a number instead of text that looks like a number.

Comment: In addition to turning on inheritance, he should also put hidden AdministrationNumber and DebtorNumber fields on his  OrderLine form.

Comment: Hmm... It works without it, so unless it's useful for some other reason...? Although, perhaps, if OrderLine documents are responses, then he should have computed for display AdministrationNumber and DebtorNumber fields, each with a formula of `@GetDocField(@Text($REF);@ThisName)`, and that would allow for backward compatibility of existing orderline documents as well as updating (when OrderLine doc is refreshed) if the Order document's AdministrationNumber and DebtorNumber fields were to change after the OrderLine document was first saved. This would make his form slightly slower, though.

Comment: I'm sure you're right. From a long, long, long time ago, I had believed that inheritance only worked if you had an actual field with the same name on the child doc's form. I'm sure I have been told on more than a few occasions that this is not true - but it's hard to unlearn those early first impressions.

Comment: JSmart523 And what If I have Order (form) ->Orderline(Form) and in that Orderline form again a Subform Orderline and in that subform there will be a subform prices.. Can I then in prices also use that formula?

Comment: When a formula refers to a variable name:

Comment: *ooops, I hit enter but multi-line comments aren't allowed. sorry. Anyway...* @bboni, When a new doc is being created by composing (i.e. opening) it in the UI, and if the form has the "Formulas inherit values from selected document" property enabled, then for the brief time that the document is being loaded, and if you have a formula that refers to a variable, and that variable is not a temporary variable nor a field already defined on the document, it will take the value from the selected document, if it exists. *(continued in next comment)*

Comment: @bboni So... it will only look to the selected doc. If always want to get a field from the main document even if you have responses to responses to responses of the main document, I'd make hidden, computed when composed "OrderDUID" fields that are `@Text(@DocumentUniqueID)` on the Order form, and `@ThisValue` on all other documents, and then I could get fields on the order form by using `@GetDocField(OrderDUID, "AdministrationNumber")`